# C,CXX compiler identification is unknown

Tags: windows, ros

I'm trying to use ROS on windows. While trying to the run the turtlebot3 tutorial (https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/Turtlebot/Turtlebot3.html)
I ran into an error.

I've tried installing Microsoft visual studio 2019 but that doesn't seem to help.

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Edge/ROS/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Edge/ROS/ws/turtlebot3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Update code formatting

Comment: This is my answer, but I'll leave as a comment. ROS, version 1, is largely unsupported on windows, with the possible exception of melodic, kinda. The recommendation is to either use a [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (free!) or dual-boot Ubuntu (16 or 18, at this point 18 is probably more preferred). Since ROS1 wasn't designed to run on Windows, the community and the support for it is small, or exclusively focused on ROS2.